# Is it possible to have line number for erlang source code?

Tags: emacs, erlang

The emacs is used and erlang code is for print. 
Because the author modifying the source code in git, sourcetree shows me line number. If the line number is printed, it is much better to quickly find it by line number. But how to configure it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [line number mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers), but you can even use goto-line to jump to a line number directly:

```
`M-g M-g'
`M-g g'
     Read a number N and move point to the beginning of line number N
     (`goto-line').  Line 1 is the beginning of the buffer.  If point
     is on or just after a number in the buffer, that is the default
     for N.  Just type <RET> in the minibuffer to use it.
```

Comment: I prefer column-number-mode, it shows the line number and column in the footer. Handy if you're concerned about line lengths as well. Add (column-number-mode 1) to your .emacs file or `M-x column-number-mode` to enable on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to have visual line numbers (like in Eclipse for instance) you can have a look at `linum-mode` (it's part of Emacs since version 23). To enable linum globally just add this line to your `.emacs` (or equivalent):

```
(global-linum-mode +1)
```

Comment: line number can really show on screen, But I actually want to print the number on paper. I have tried this method, no line number on paper.

Comment: If you want to print the text with line numbers then it doesn't have to be done by emacs, because it's not an editing job. Search on google for tools which can print your text files with line numbers,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `a2ps` to create the printout.  It accepts the options `-C` (put line number on every fifth line) and `--line-number=NUM` (put line number on every NUMth line).  For example:

```
a2ps -o foo.ps -C foo.erl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html#ch1_1).

It supports both line numbering and Erlang syntax highlighting.